# WiFi name keeps changing but not by me

Tags: network, wifi

Over the last year I continue to get notifications that my WiFi has changed.  I have xfinity and have changed my equipment twice and updated my settings to be more secure as follows:

- changed default gateway password
- do not broadcast WiFi name
- created long WiFi name and password
- changed to wpa2
- disabled WiFi hotspot

I also view devices on my network. At one point there were numerous unknown devices which I have since blocked.

I use only iPad and iPhone and have stopped using my PC as I’m worried it is being compromised.

Can someone have a repeater or extender in my network without my knowledge?  How can they do this?

How can someone change my WiFi name?

How can I tell if my WiFi is hacked?

What else should I be looking for?

Is net analyzer for iOS a good option?

Are cookies from my surfing the problem?

Comment: Does anyone have physical access to your devices? They could be changing the name the same way you are.

Comment: What I would suggest is that you view devices on your network using your router's / modem's web interface, and not a Windows / android / iPhone app, if this is what you were doing. (These apps may not show everything) Is there anything you dont recognize ? If you use powerline ethernet adapters, some types can give your neighbors access to your network. Try disconnecting them, if you use them. Does your ISP offer a web interface where you can manage your account / pay your bills / etc. ? Some ISPs let you change your WiFi password from there, so change the password on that, too.

Comment: Also, if you do recognise all the devices on your network, try disconnecting / turning off each one for a period of time, and see if the problem persists. You may be able to narrow down the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done all those changes to your router and the WiFi "name" or SSID is being changed then you could possibly have a compromised device on your network.  This isn't guaranteed to be the problem as some routers allow remote management so it could be the case that someone is able to connect from a remote location and perform changes.  One question to ask yourself is why they would need/ want to make changes?  If it was a malicious person that had compromised your desktop computer for example, they might want to maintain access for a longer period of time, and by making changes this is more likely to alert you to their activities.  I would suggest it is possibly more likely to be someone who is playing a joke and trying to wind you up??